# combinatorics: even numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There are given 6 numbers: 1,2,4,6,7,8. I need to find out how many 5 number combinations are there ($A_6^5$=720) and how many of those combinations are even numbers. The numbers can't recur. The book says its 480, I get the same answer but I'm not sure if I'm solving it right $${A_6^5*4\over 6}$$
This is my answer. You divide all your combinations into 6 parts (amount of possible endings) and multiply by those, that are needed (in this case even numbers are 4: 2,4,6,8). Is this the right way to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, a more convincing approach might be to say the last digit has to be even and the first four digits can be any of the other five in some order i.e.

$$4 \times (5 \times 4 \times 3 \times 2).$$

Comment: Isn't my way of solving basically the same? I take the numbers from the first equation (finding out how many combinations can there be) in this case 2*3*4*5*6 I then divide the sum by 6 (neglecting the last number of the combination) and then multiplying by 4 (adding the 4 possibilities)

Comment: Yes it is, and I do not think your answer is wrong. But your approach requires the extra thought that the number of original solutions ending with each possible digit is the same and so you can use $\frac46$ of the previous answer.  While completely true in this case, it may confuse some readers.

Answer (score 0):

For first four digits you have $6*6*6*6=6^4$ possibilities (in each of 4 digit-places you could put 6 numbers) and for the last digit you have 4 possible digits. So, final answer is $4*6^4$ if repeating of numbers is allowed.

If repeating of numbers is not allowed: for last digit-place we have 4 possible digits(2,4,6,8), after that for the next digit-place we chose digit among 5 remaining digits, then for the next digit-place we have 4 remaining digits, ... Therefore, in this case we have $4*5*4*3*2=480$ possible numbers.

Comment: Forgot to add that the numbers cant recur